# How to add an image to an already drawn box using LWJGL & Slick2D

Tags: java, image, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I am creating a simple 2D game for my computer class.  I already have a box that moves around through a level.  But, i want to change this box to instead display a stickman standing that I drew. Then, more specifically, i would like in my MovementInput class (where i assign movements to the buttons), I want when neither A(my moving left button) or D(my moving right button) OR when both A and D are held down to display this standing.png image.  How would i go about doing this?!

This is my code for drawing the box

```
public class Man extends AbstractMoveableEntity {
    public Man(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        glColor3d(0, 0, 255);
        glRectd(x - width / 2, y, x + width / 2, y + height);
    }
}
```

And in my MovementInput class, this is my code for the A&D thing

```
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D) &&Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))||(!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D) && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))) {
    man.setDX(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something called [Texture Atlases](http://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping) for multiple frames of animation and a simple timer to loop through the frames. [ThinMatrix](https://www.youtube.com/user/ThinMatri) on YouTube has a really good tutorial for this  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T182r4F6J8) as well as many other concepts.